# OnDestory() being called when switching back to fragment with NavigationUI

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview, android-navigation

I am using NavigationUI with bottom navigation view and have also set it up with the action bar.

My app starts with the home fragment and when I switch to my search fragment `OnDestroyView()` is called on the `homeFragment` (expected) but when I switch back from the search fragment to my home fragment `onDestroy()` is called and then a new instance of `homefragment` is displayed rather than the one that it resuming at the state I left it in. How do I get it to resume at the state it was before?

**This is how I have set up my NavigationUI:**

```
NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this,
         R.id.navigation_host_fragment);

NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(mainBinding.mainActivityBn, navController);
NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this,navController);
```

**My Nav Graph:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_activity_navigation"
app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">

  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
    android:name=<name>
    android:label="Home"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/serachFragment"
    android:name=<name>
    android:label="Search"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_search" />

 </navigation>
```

**Edit:** I am using Bottom Navigation View to navigate between the fragments. When I press the back button the home fragment is loaded as it was in the previous state (expected behaviour).

Comment: How are you switching back to your home fragment (by hitting the system back button? by tapping that item on the bottom nav?)? Can you include your navigation graph?

Comment: @ianhanniballake by using the bottom navigation View

Comment: Can you include your navigation graph?

Comment: And just to clarify, do you see different behavior when you hit the system back button?

Comment: Yes @ianhanniballake the back button displays the home fragment without reloading it . Which is what I want to do when I click home on the bottom nav as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/156400382#comment5):

> To understand the logic here, we need to look at what `NavigationUI` does when you select a destination. Looking at [the source code](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:navigation/navigation-ui/src/main/java/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI.java;l=73) and removing the unrelated code (animations, secondary menu code):
>
> ```
> NavOptions.Builder builder = new NavOptions.Builder()
>   .setLaunchSingleTop(true);
> builder.setPopUpTo(findStartDestination(navController.getGraph()).getId(), false);
> NavOptions options = builder.build();
> navController.navigate(item.getItemId(), null, options);
> ```
>
> So the `popUpTo` pops up to the root destination, but uses `false` to not pop the root destination itself. It then uses `setLaunchSingleTop(true)` to avoid having two instances of the start destination on the back stack. The intent here is to not clear any `ViewModel` or `SavedStateHandle` associated with that root destination when you go back to it.
>
> So NavController calls `navigate()`, we pop everything up to but not including the start destination (your first screen) off the back stack, correctly removing the second screen.
>
> NavController then calls through to `FragmentNavigator` to do the `navigate()` call. `FragmentNavigator` sees the `launchSingleTop` is true and correctly determines that the fragment is already on the top of the stack. However, Fragments, unlike activities, do not have any equivalent to `onNewIntent()` for `onNewArguments()` for mimicking the `singleTop` behavior, so `FragmentNavigator` pops the previous fragment and adds a new instance of the Fragment, passing in the new arguments (here, just `null`).

So due to how Fragments handle the `setLaunchSingleTop(true)` flag, clicking the first item in the bottom nav destroys and recreates the Fragment again. This is why the system back button acts differently - the system back button is just calling `popBackStack()` and not using any of the single top behavior.

That issue is still open and indicates that:

> The behavior of `FragmentNavigator` with single top is bad and should feel bad. It does not match the behavior of activities and is unintuitive. If you don't mind, let's use this bug to track that work. Ideally, a new instance would *not* be created, meaning your original MapFragment would just be resumed and would be right back where it was. This would be consistent with what happens when you hit the system back button.

There's no direct workaround to that issue, so the best result (not having this happen) would require that you star that issue and wait for it be fixed. However, you'll note that any state or ViewModels you save into your [NavBackStackEntry](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#navbackstackentry) *would* be saved over a `singleTop` operation:

```
// Instead of using this:
myViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel.class);

// You could use:
NavController navController = NavHostFragment.findNavController(this);
NavBackStackEntry entry = navController.getBackStackEntry(R.id.homeFragment);
myViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(entry).get(MyViewModel.class);
```

However, this would not help with saving the Fragment's view state (i.e., scroll position) since those aren't possible to save into the NavBackStackEntry, but are only
saved at the Fragment level.